Property of mean preserving spread
Consider two random variables $X\sim F$ and $Y\sim G$, both on $[0,1]$. Suppose $X$ is a mean preserving spread of $Y$, i.e.,
$$ \int_t^1 F(x)dx \le \int_t^1 G(x)dx $$
for all $t\in[0,1]$ and equality holds when $t=0$.
Prove or disprove the following:$$ \int_t^1 F(x)dG(x) \le \int_t^1 G(x)dF(x) $$
for all $t\in[0,1]$ and equality holds when $t=0$.

As an example, consider $F(x)=x$ and $G(x)=\mathbb{1}\{x\ge 1/2\}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
(LHS)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }t>\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} &\text{if }t\le\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases},\ 
(RHS)=\begin{cases}
1-t &\text{if }t>\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} &\text{if }t\le\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the inequality holds for all $t\in[0,1]$. Moreover, equality holds for $t=0$.
Another example: $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{1}\{x=1\}\frac{1}{2}$ and $G(x)=x$. Then,
\begin{align*}
(LHS)=\frac{1}{2}(1-t),\ (RHS)=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Again, the inequality holds for all $t\in[0,1]$. Moreover, equality holds for $t=0$.

Here is a counterexample:
$F(x)=\frac{2}{3}+\mathbb{1}\{x=1\}\frac{1}{3}$ and $G(x)=2x-x^2$. Then,
\begin{align*}
(LHS)=\frac{2}{3}(1-t)^2,\ (RHS)=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, (LHS) is strictly larger than (RHS) for small $t$ (e.g. $t=0$).
